# Pass a string variable from an activity into a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hi I'm trying to pass a string variable from an activity into a fragment but it's always null.

Firstly I set the variable value, then create the bundle in the Activity:

```
String results = setResultCaption(bothEarsBad, leftEarBad, rightEarBad).toString();
```

Then

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("resultsString", results);
RightEarResults rightEarResults = new RightEarResults();
rightEarResults.setArguments(bundle);
```

I then call the `bundle` from the fragment `onCreateView` method as follows:

```
String bundle = getArguments().getString("resultsString");
```

And then set the variable in the `TextView`

```
txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.results_text);
txt.setText(bundle);
```

Can anyone help me understand why it's always null.

Comment: Your code looks alright. can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: Have you tried moving `String bundle` to `onViewCreated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a `newInstance()` method for your `Fragment` and hand over the parameter there:

```
public static YourFragment newInstance(String valueToPass) {

   YourFragment f = new YourFragment();

   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("key", valueToPass);
   f.setArguments(b);

   return f;
}
```

In your `Actitity`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.newInstance(stringtoPass), "yourFragTag").commit();
```

Inside your `Fragment`, you can then retrieve the value by using the `getArguments()` method:

```
String yourvalue = getArguments().getString("key");
```

**EDIT :** Also, please check if your `setResultCaption(...)` method **actually returns something, and not NULL.**

Comment: thanks for the help! so will I still have to call FragmentTransaction.add in the activity?

Comment: Yes you can use add instead of replace as well.

Comment: the part I don't really get is what I pass into 'replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.newInstance(stringtoPass), "yourFragTag")' what is the R.id.container, is it the textview i want to pass the string into? and "yourFragtag" is that just a string in my fragment? I created a string called 'public static final String IS_RIGHT_EAR = "is_right_ear";' is this what i pass in and do I bass the value or the reference?

Comment: R.id.container is the layout in your .xml file that will contain the Fragment. Usually, a FrameLayout is used for that.

Comment: "yourFragTag" is a tag for your Fragment, an identifier that will enable you to find your Fragment and access it. It is not really needed in your case.

Comment: The string is now passed into the interface on the fragment, but returns null at 'resultTxt = getArguments().getString("key");' how can that be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass variables on fragment initialisation, you can :

- Use a bundle as parameter of `Fragment.setArgument()` method
- Use a static method with your variables as parameters. Check @Philipp Jahoda's answer.

If you want to pass variables to fragment after initialisation, you can refer to [this post](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) from the official doc

Answer (score 0):

**You can just do:**

From your activity;

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Yourclass.class);
passIntent.addExtra("resultsString",results);
startActivity(passIntent);
```

In your fragment;

```
Intent intentBundle = getActivity().getIntent();
        String someresult= intentBundle.getStringExtra("resultsString");
        Log.i("Result : ", someresult);
```

And then,

```
txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.results_text);
txt.setText(someresult);
```